# Add a field to a document

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, logstash

In particular, we have a tons of log messages constantly coming in the following format:

```
Jul 23 09:24:16 mmr mmr-core[5147]:  Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656876839.mt
Jul 23 09:24:18 mmr mmr-core[5210]:  Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656876839.0.dn
```

There are different id numbers (1563866656876839) and two possible suffixes (mt/dn).

We parse it with logstash and store these messages in one index.

When the id number with mt suffix gots dn suffix within 1 hour it means GOOD and it should get a new field status with approved value in it. If not the field value should be disapproved.

So in the end a new index isn't needed :D But I'm still curious how to achieve that and if it is even possible to create and fill the new field in document based on a time condition or how to say...

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: What kind of condition? What should trigger this copy? One time or recurring?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I specified my problem it below in my answer.

Comment: In logstash you add fields with the [add_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) option. And you can use [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.4/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) in your configuration to filter your events.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to create and fill the new field in document based on a time condition.

First you have to create three [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filters with `task_id` as your id. One filter to create a map and second filter to submit the map as an event. In last filter there should be `timeout` option in case of your timeout scenario.